# Как редактировать сообщения бота, отправленные в группу телеграма?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Есть группа в телеграме. В группу добавлен и работает бот.
Через @ControllerBot я подвязал группу и своего бота.
Теперь могу через меню бота выкладывать посты с кнопками (как раз кнопки и хотелось изначально использовать). Но при попытке редактировать уже созданный пост, мне выдаёт ошибку:

"Вы можете отредактировать только сообщения из канала."

Вопрос: как редактировать сообщения, созданные через бота в группе?

Comment: это к разработчикам данного бота

Comment: Связаться с разработчиками не получилось. В итоге вышел из ситуации следующим образом. Создал в телеграме канал, добавил туда своего бота. В канал добавил свою группу, как чат для обсуждения. И теперь публикуя в канале пост (с кнопками), пост автоматически дублируется в группе. Так что фактически задача решена. Посты можно править.